# how to load facebook javascripts from my code behind in c# in asp.net

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

Some times the Facebook resources are not load for eg.all.js file that collapse my application  is that good to host in local. i've come across the question already raised on this issue.please suggest me any idea to recursively to  check the whether the resources loaded or not from code behind  in c# else through java script.or  any temporarily solutions to avoid this conditions, and also i came to knew that locally hosting will not reflect the changes made in the live by the facebook people so please let me know any idea to overcome the problem

thanks 
chandru.v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot host the Facebook JavaScript files locally on your own server.  They have to be ran from Facebook's site to work due to cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: thanks man i got it, but how do i overcome this situation if resources are not loaded.as a technical people we will know but users doesn't thats my point.